# Why do some servers have /etc/sysconfig/kernel and others do not?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I spent some time looking into this and couldn't figure out why there are servers with and without `/etc/sysconfig/kernel`.

What's particularly interesting is that we have some servers with the same underlying architecture (kernel and OS) that have the file and others don't.

It's my understanding that the `/etc/sysconfig/kernel` configuration file controls the kernel selection at boot, specifically with the `UPDATEDEFAULT` and `DEFAULTKERNEL` parameters, but the file is missing on some servers. I would assume without this file the boot sequence isn't impacted. Is that safe to say?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sysconfig` is a RedHat-specific config directory, so you are not going to find it on, say, Debian derivates.

For example, on a Rockly Linux 8 (a RHEL clone), `/etc/sysconfig/kernel` contains the following

```
# UPDATEDEFAULT specifies if kernel-install should make
# new kernels the default
UPDATEDEFAULT=yes

# DEFAULTKERNEL specifies the default kernel package type
DEFAULTKERNEL=kernel-core
```

As you can see, it has specific instruction for the package manager regarding which kernel to install and select as default.